# JSR303 Validation - Bean's property as Message Parameter

Tags: validation, bean-validation

In JSR303 validation,is it possible to pass the bean's property as parameter for validation message ?

Ex.

```
class BeanA { 

private String userName;
@Min(value=15, message="Age of {userName} should be greater than {value}")
private int age;

public BeanA(String userName,int age){
//initialization
}

}
```

For an object `BeanA("Ahamed", 12)` , I should get error "*Age of **Ahamed** should be greater than 15*"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you can pass to annotation parameter only constant values. Since you need to evaluate value of message, it cannot be set as annotation parameter.

As a matter of fact, you don't really need to do this, default error message tells more or less what is going on, although it is not as informative as you would like.

Comment: When there is a list of BeanA , we want to validate, I hope this error message will be useful.